# Openssl_Decrypt method in .net not working as in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a PHP code sample showing how to decrypt a certain message. I'm trying to decrypt that message using C#, but no luck yet.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
public static string AesDecrypt(byte[] dataToDecrypt, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            //aes.KeySize = 256;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(dataToDecrypt))
            {
                var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is how I'm calling the method:

```
        var aesKey = GenerateSha256Hash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("t-3zafRa"));

        var aesIv = GenerateSha256Hash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("St@cE4eZ"));
        var ivString = ConvertByteArrayToSring(aesIv).Substring(0, 16);

        // I'm getting a 24 byte array here, but message needs to be multiple of 16, isn't it?
        var encryptedText = Convert.FromBase64String("RmVpUjU4VjJlcXp2dkN5UlhUODQzUT09");


        var aesDecryptedBytes = AesDecrypt(encryptedText, aesKey, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivString));
```

Here are the User-defined methods from above:

```
public static byte[] GenerateSha256Hash(byte[] toBeHashed)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return sha256.ComputeHash(toBeHashed);
        }
    }

    public static string ConvertByteArrayToSring(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var t in bytes)
        {
            builder.Append(t.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

The PHP code sample I have is bellow:

```
php > $secret_key = "t-3zafRa";
$secret_iv = "St@cE4eZ";
php > $encrypted_txt = "RmVpUjU4VjJlcXp2dkN5UlhUODQzUT09";
php > $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
php > $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
php > $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
php > echo openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_txt), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
```

I'm getting correct value for Key, IV and even the message when I'm converting it from base64String but the final call to Openssl_Decrypt seems not working for me.

I'm getting an error which says "Input data is not a complete block", which is kind of expected, I tried to remove first and last 8 byte as IV from the message to make it a 16 byte, but I'm still getting jibberish.

What I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Post the PHP code and the missing user-defined methods.

Comment: @Topaco Updated the post as suggested.

Comment: secret_key definition is missing in PHP code?

Comment: No, I missed that while copying, it's just another variable, I will update it now.

Comment: and the 0 argument in openssl_decrypt is OPENSSL_RAW_DATA or OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, and what do these options mean anyway?

Comment: As far as I read, 0 means no padding.

Comment: Currently, the PHP-`hash` function returns the result as a hex-string, resulting in a length of 64 bytes. Therefore, a 64 byte key is used that is implicitly truncated. Is that really what you want? Please check if the result should not be returned better binary (this is achieved by setting the third parameter of the [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function to `true`)? The same issue applies to the IV.

Comment: Did Topaco's comments solve the issue for you? If so you can either delete the question or post an answer yourself. Or, if you are extremely nice, you first give Topaco the chance to answer and *then* do it yourself if Topaco doesn't.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue actually, and the guys who coded the PHP part, said it's troublesome to decrypt it in C#. They are going to make an api for us to get the decrypted value.